# ¿Hay forma de contar cuantas tuplas que comienzan con 1, por ejemplo, hay en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, tuplas

Es decir, si tengo:

```
lista = [(1,2),(2,5),(3,1),(1,0),(1,5)]
```

y quiero contar cuantas tuplas tienen como primer dato el 1, me devuelva 3. Sin tener que usar un for, se que con for se podría, pero ¿es la única y la mejor forma?

Comment: `sum([1 for x in lista if x[0] == 1])`

Comment: Otra forma `len([x for x in lista if x[0] ==1])`

Comment: Y otra más, aprovechando que un booleano de valor `True` vale 1 y uno de valor `False` vale 0 a la hora de ser sumados: `sum(x[0]==1 for x in lista)`